# hplip/hpcups "libImageProcessor.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Tags: debian, printing, cups

I have a Debian 10 system, and a HP OfficeJet Pro 8020 printer.  Debian 10 does not include drivers for this model.  HP provide [manual upgrade instructions](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/install/manual/distros/debian) for 64-bit Debian... Debian version 6.

Some of the packages you need to install first might have changed names.  I mostly cheated - I used `apt build-dep hplip`, to get all the build dependencies from the older Debian version.

The build succeeded.  I can now see the driver for my specific printer, and I can set it up in CUPS.  My problem is it is not able to print anything.

`/var/log/cups/error_log` contains this line:

```
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/bannertopdf (PID 18088)
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf (PID 18089)
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster (PID 18090)
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/hpcups (PID 18091)
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] Started backend /usr/lib/cups/backend/ipp (PID 18092)
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] 172.16.1.160: error while loading shared libraries: libImageProcessor.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] PID 18091 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/hpcups) stopped with status 127 (File too large)
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
```

Confusingly, sometimes the order changes, so that "stopped with status 127" is printed first.  More confusingly, there are many more log messages after this error.  One of them is "broken pipe", as if CUPS sets up a pipeline of processes, which all collapses when hpcups dies.

```
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] OUTFORMAT=\"(null)\", so output format will be CUPS/PWG Raster
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] pdftopdf: Last filter determined by the PPD: hpcups; FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE: application/vnd.cups-raster => pdftopdf will not log pages in page_log.
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] Sending stdin for job...
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] STATE: +connecting-to-device
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] Looking up \"172.16.1.160\"...
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] STATE: -connecting-to-device
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] 172.16.1.160=172.16.1.160
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] PDF template file doesn\'t have form. It\'s okay.
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] hrDeviceDesc=\"HP OfficeJet Pro 8020 series\"
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] PID 18089 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf) exited with no errors.
```

```
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] Error: /ioerror in --showpage--
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] Operand stack:
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] true   (/var/spool/cups/tmp/gs_yQ9gF3)   --nostringval--   1   true
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] Execution stack:
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   showpage   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   showpage   showpage   false   1   %stopped_push   1992   2   3   %oparray_pop   1991   2   3   %oparray_pop   1979   2   3   %oparray_pop   showpage   1980   4   3   %oparray_pop   showpage   showpage   2   1   1   showpage   %for_pos_int_continue   1983   4   7   %oparray_pop   showpage   showpage   1840   3   9   %oparray_pop   showpage   showpage
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] Dictionary stack:
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] --dict:736/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:80/200(L)--   --dict:80/200(L)--   --dict:133/256(ro)(G)--   --dict:315/325(ro)(G)--   --dict:33/64(L)--   --dict:6/9(L)--   --dict:7/20(L)--
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] Current allocation mode is local
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] Last OS error: Broken pipe
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] GPL Ghostscript 9.27: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] prtMarkerSuppliesMaxCapacity.1.3 = 100
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] Rendering completed
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] prtMarkerSuppliesMaxCapacity.1.4 = 100
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] PID 18090 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster) stopped with status 1.
D [09/Aug/2020:16:33:07 +0100] [Job 194] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirmed it is a problem with the library path:

```
$ ldd /usr/lib/cups/filter/hpcups | grep libImageProcessor
    libImageProcessor.so => not found
```

Note this step in the manual instructions:

```
./configure --with-hpppddir=/usr/share/ppd/HP --libdir=/usr/lib64 --prefix=/usr --enable-qt4 --disable-libusb01_build --enable-doc-build --disable-cups-ppd-install --disable-foomatic-drv-install --disable-foomatic-ppd-install --disable-hpijs-install --disable-udev_sysfs_rules --disable-policykit --enable-cups-drv-install --enable-hpcups-install --enable-network-build --enable-dbus-build --enable-scan-build --enable-fax-build
```

There are only a few files in `/usr/lib64/`, and all but one of them were installed by hplip.  The correct library path on Debian 10 is `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`.  If you have built using the wrong path already, run `make clean`.  Then, vary the instructions to use this configure command instead:

`./configure --with-hpppddir=/usr/share/ppd/HP --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-qt4 --disable-libusb01_build --enable-doc-build --disable-cups-ppd-install --disable-foomatic-drv-install --disable-foomatic-ppd-install --disable-hpijs-install --disable-udev_sysfs_rules --disable-policykit --enable-cups-drv-install --enable-hpcups-install --enable-network-build --enable-dbus-build --enable-scan-build --enable-fax-build`